# What is the difference between 旅, 留 and 驻?

Tags: difference, word

The context is that of (I think?) a "visiting scholar" in France: 旅法学者

旅, 留 and 驻 all refer to a type of staying or residing abroad, but what are the exact differences in their uses?

And if "visiting scholar" is correct, then what is the difference (if any), between 旅[country]学者 and 访学/访问学者?

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

旅 = to travel

留 = to stay

驻 = to station

The 旅 in 旅法学者  is short for **旅居** (sojourning)

旅法学者 = 旅居法国的外籍学者 is a scholar currently living in France as a foreigner.

The 留 in 留法學生 is short for **留学** (study abroad)

留法学生 = 留学法国的外籍留学生 is a foreign student studying in France

The 驻 in 驻法軍人 is short for **驻守** (station)

驻法軍人 = 驻守法国的外籍軍人 is a foreign soldier who stations in France

"旅X YY" describes an artist or scholar e.g. 旅法音樂家, 旅法作家, 旅法考古家, or simply a foreigner e.g. 旅美华人, 旅港加人

"留X 学生" describes students e.g. 留英学生, 留美学生, 留法学生

"驻X YY" describes an international organization, government, or military personnel e.g. CNN 驻英記者, 国际特赦组织驻俄監察員, 驻港大使, 驻中大使, 驻日美軍, 驻德美軍

访 in 访法学者 is short for 访问 (visiting)  *he can be visiting France for a few hours, a few days, or a few months; 旅法学者 usually staying in France for years or even for his or her entire life*

Comment: Brilliant explanation, 谢谢你。